# How to change image opacity?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two images in a list view.
First image's opacity is 1 and other is 0. When the first image  is tapped, the image's opacity will be 0 and the other will be 1.. I already know how to use tap gesture but I can't figure out how to do this. . Please help

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="app1"  Title="List">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
<ListView x:Name="ListView" HasUnevenRows="true"  >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell>
<Grid>
<Image  Source="iombuttondisable.png" Opacity="1" >
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Interested_OnClicked"/>
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
<Image  Source="iombutton.png" Opacity="0" >
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Interested_OnClicked"/>
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
</Grid>
</Grid>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>                               
</ListView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Show your approach :)

Comment: here is the XAML  http://imgur.com/51B8Ue6
i am planning to make like a Like/unlike function in facebook.. hope you will help me

Comment: Edit your post and paste the code :)

Comment: it's over the character limit

Comment: Your question. not the comment ;)

Comment: I updated my Post :)

Comment: May be try to add an overlay and add the image to the overlay and change the opacity of that overlay?